# Best collection to store unique path

Tags: .net, memory-management, collections

I need to store a huge number of unique path like: `"C:\MyDir\MySubDir\myfile.txt"`.

I want to be able to quickly check if a path is contained in my collection, and above, to use less memory as possible.

What is the most suitable [collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sbxh9x2) for this task?

Is it possible to store a value that represent the unique path, instead of the string itself, to use less memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have answered, a `Trie` and `HashSet` would provide fast fetching times.
Due note, that while a `Trie` will require less than a `HashSet`, **both will require more memory than a plain old `List`** (see [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/)).

I don't know if it is really [necessary](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html), but if memory is a real issue here, you could optimize the `Trie` implementation, using folder names as nodes instead of letters (as usually folder names are longer than one letter). This way you will use the tree structure of the paths.

Comment: +1 for the folder optimization idea.  It might prove useful for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) We did very efficiently with 20 millions path

Answer (score 2):

A hash set, if you need quick access to the data, i.e. if you want to know if something exists in the collection in O(1) time.

In .NET 4, use a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438). It's like a hashtable, but only the value is stored, not a key/value pair.

```
HashSet<string> myStrings = new HashSet<string>();
myStrings.Add(@"c:\foo\bar.txt");
myStrings.Add(@"c:\foo\baz.gif");
myStrings.Add(@"c:\foo\bat.bin");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, his is my favorite style of response, clear, complete and with examples +1

Comment: P Campbell is the one who deserves the praise by the way.  I only wrote the beginnings of the answer, the rest, including the example, was supplied by him/her.  Thank you P Campbell

Answer (score 2):

This is most suited to a [TRIE](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/trie/).  Here is an example: [implementing a trie in c#](http://www.kerrywong.com/2006/04/01/implementing-a-trie-in-c/).

To answer your question, **yes, a TRIE stores the unique path rather than the string itself.**

Tries are very efficient for your task, both in memory consumption and in execution speed.

**Edit:**
It's not that one is better than the other, **TRIEs were invented for this type of storage/retrieval problem** and are quite efficient.  **Hashing is also fast**.  If you want to know which one best suits your needs, implement both.  It shouldn't take long either way.  **Measure, measure, measure.**

Comment: Why a trie is better than HashSet?

Comment: Ok, your answer was helpful +1

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use Dictionary/HashTable for the purpose which would give you a fast look up collection.

"s it possible to store a value that rappresent the unique path.."- Think about this, every time when you have to check some value exists in the collection, you have to encript/decrypt your string. Not good approach

**EDIT :**
If Speed is not the issue, why not store all the keys in database and then you can probably make quick loop up in the table to see whether the path exists or not ?

Comment: It depends, in my case it is not a problem because, as i wrote, memory usage is more important than speed. Obviously I'm not going to use a simple list.

Comment: Manage a dababase with hundreds of thousands paths is even worse than use a list, don't you think?

Comment: At some place you have to make compromise !

Answer (score 0):

A data structure often used to store unique data points is a set.  You can use the .NET [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) class for this.  Using an HashSet, you wouldn't have to check if a value exists before adding it, and you would get quick lookup as well.